# Center elements of HorizontalScrollView when not enough to make it scroll

Tags: android, layout, element, center, horizontalscrollview

I have a Layout with a `HorizontalScrollView` containing a `LinearLayout` for a Menu where the contents are inflated with the contents of the DB.  This works fine however when there are not enough elements to make the `HSV` scroll this does not fill the width of the screen which ideally should be centered. i.e.
Currently:

```
| Element 1 Element 2                         | <- edge of screen
```

Instead of:

```
|        Element 1            Element 2       | <- edge of screen
```

whilst still being able to:

```
| Element 1 Element 2 Element 3 Element 4 Elem| <- edge of screen now scrolling
```

The layout XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLinearLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView 
         android:id="@+id/header"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="25dp" >
    </TextView>

    <ScrollView
         android:id="@+id/scroll1"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:layout_weight="1" >

        <LinearLayout
             android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:orientation="vertical" >

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/footerLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        </LinearLayout>
   </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

With the following XML being inflated inside footerLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

        <TextView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/footer_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:text="FOOTER"
            android:singleLine="true" />
```

Answer (score 35):

I just solved this issue. I ran into it a few hours ago. You need to center the HorizontalScrollView in its parent and set its width/height to wrap_content. The layout you put in the the HSV must have its width/height set to wrap content as well. The important part here is to not set any gravity/layout_gravity on this layout or you may experience (very annoying) clipping issues after inflating your views. Example below is contained in a RelativeLayout.

```
 <HorizontalScrollView  android:id="@+id/svExample"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/rlExample">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llExample"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView >
```

Comment: For me it worked correctly the properties:

android: layout_centerHorizontal = "true" 
android: layout_width = "wrap_content"

Answer (score 8):

Below is the simplest way worked for me.

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_others"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: This is brilliant!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem and finally got it to work. Here is a minimal example:

The main activity layout with the HorizontalScrollView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The layout of the elements that will be inflated and put inside the scroll view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="your text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is an example of the code to inflate and add the elements:

```
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);
LayoutParams elementLayoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
int elementCount = 3; // ...or however many you like
for (int i = 0; i < elementCount; i++) {
    LinearLayout element = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.element, null);
    container.addView(element, elementLayoutParams);
}
```

It's mainly based on a technique for stretching the content of ScrollViews explained in [this article by Romain Guy](http://www.curious-creature.org/2010/08/15/scrollviews-handy-trick/).

However in this case where you are adding contents dynamically, another key point is setting the positive value for the weight (1f in this example) using LayoutParams when adding the elements to the container. If you have a static set of elements that you can include directly in the container and don't need to inflate you can specify the weight of the elements' outer LinearLayout in the XML layout like so:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

But if you do it dynamically that won't work because the weight will reset to 0 and the elements collapse. Hence you need to set it via the LayoutParams.

Comment: `fillViewport="true"` was the missing piece I was looking for to solve my similar problem. For future readers: if you're experiencing really weird left-side clipping of your centered `TextView` inside the `HorizontalScrollView`, try tweaking with the `fillViewport` attribute. It allows weights to be turned on.

Comment: the article by Romain Guy helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

managed to get round center-horizontal clipping the left side:

HorizontalScrollView part of layout has been changed to:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:id="@+id/footerWrapperLayoutToGetAroundCenteringIssue"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">

    <HorizontalScrollView 
        android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout 
            android:id="@+id/footerLayout" 
            android:orientation="horizontal" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Its just a pity when it centers them they are not evenly distributed.

If anyone has any ideas please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If the parent layout is a constraint layout:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            .
            .
        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

assign wieght 1 to the textview in inflated view and make width wrapcontent

Comment: has no effect, still looks the same

Comment: it seems like the LinearLayout footerLayout does not expand to fill the full width if only one or two elements are inside.

Comment: try one more thing may be it works assign wieght sum to linearlayout in ur code to whatever number of elements ur inserting and assign the wieght 1 in xml to the textView to be inflated.